# Aligning text in a geomatric shaped div

Tags: css, html, text, area

Can i align a text in a div with a geometric shape, like this 
https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQ5z8OYxnypDr09mmfFMunJj31x_XtfG3MFj0vlAa_ceoCnts0OfQ

without hiding some of text?

Update:

I need something like this, above is a circle, but also i need something like this for parallelogram:

http://i39.tinypic.com/4r2ikm.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a js fiddle code

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/upq6L/)

Found it some where.

Here's the script

```
var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");

var text = "'Twas the night before Christmas, when all through the house,  Not a creature was stirring, not even a mouse.  And so begins the story of the day of Christmas";
var font = "12pt verdana";
var textHeight = 15;
var lineHeight = textHeight + 5;
var lines = [];

var cx = 150;
var cy = 150;
var r = 100;

initLines();

wrapText();

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(cx, cy, r, 0, Math.PI * 2, false);
ctx.closePath();
ctx.strokeStyle = "skyblue";
ctx.lineWidth = 2;
ctx.stroke();


// pre-calculate width of each horizontal chord of the circle
// This is the max width allowed for text

function initLines() {

    for (var y = r * .90; y > -r; y -= lineHeight) {

        var h = Math.abs(r - y);

        if (y - lineHeight < 0) {
            h += 20;
        }

        var length = 2 * Math.sqrt(h * (2 * r - h));

        if (length && length > 10) {
            lines.push({
                y: y,
                maxLength: length
            });
        }

    }
}


// draw text on each line of the circle

function wrapText() {

    var i = 0;
    var words = text.split(" ");

    while (i < lines.length && words.length > 0) {

        line = lines[i++];

        var lineData = calcAllowableWords(line.maxLength, words);

        ctx.fillText(lineData.text, cx - lineData.width / 2, cy - line.y + textHeight);

        words.splice(0, lineData.count);
    };

}


// calculate how many words will fit on a line

function calcAllowableWords(maxWidth, words) {

    var wordCount = 0;
    var testLine = "";
    var spacer = "";
    var fittedWidth = 0;
    var fittedText = "";

    ctx.font = font;

    for (var i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {

        testLine += spacer + words[i];
        spacer = " ";

        var width = ctx.measureText(testLine).width;

        if (width > maxWidth) {
            return ({
                count: i,
                width: fittedWidth,
                text: fittedText
            });
        }

        fittedWidth = width;
        fittedText = testLine;

    }

}
```

Answer (score -1):

yes this can be achieved through these links

[link1](http://css-tricks.com/examples/ShapesOfCSS/) and [link2](http://www.css3shapes.com).

and then set the `div`'s by giving [postioning](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/position) :) cheers.

give border radius and get your shape. and use some margins to get it accurate. The link i have posted will help you.

Comment: I know the first link; it does not allow me to place text in it as i wanted:  http://jsfiddle.net/2ZZbx/